# Is it possible to add a vscode-python linter from another extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

The vscode-python extension supports [several linters](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).

Is it possible for another extension to add to the list of linters that vscode-python supports? Are there any materials or examples that would help someone do this?

Comment: To understand you correctly: You want a linter `foo` that does not exist as a VS code extension to be an extension?  - I guess you *could* write an extension yourself and add it locally or, depending on the linters licence, perhaps even publish it. But I doubt there is an easy way, unless there is some kind of toolkit that says "convert this part of software to an extension"

Comment: Ah, to clarify, I'm happy to write code for an extension. Say I've got a new python command that produces errors like mypy, flake8, etc. I'd like people using vscode to be able to see errors from this command in vscode. The [vscode-python linter source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/tree/main/src/client/linters) looks rather modular, so I was curious whether it possible for another extension to inject a linter in there somehow.